# How to generate two dependent Gaussian Process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, gaussian-process

If we have two dependent Gaussian Process and using SE covariance to describe it, how can we generate the two process at the same time using R?

What I was thinking is to firstly generate the two dependent Gaussian Process independently and then, using the outcome of the two process to calculate the covariance structure between the two process, is it ok? Or anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Could you please explain what "SE covariance" is?

Comment: Squared Exponential Covariance